# Crystal Report Line Object in Formula

Tags: crystal-reports, report

it's me again asking about crystal report :D

i would like to ask how can i do this in crystal report?

the "In Accredited Hospital" is a database item and items from a-g is hard coded.

[image]

i tried to do this in the formula field however my result is not the same as the above picture, is there any other solution to this?

This is my result

[image]

formula i used:

```
    stringVar emergencyCare := "";
if {DBField} = "In Accredited Hospitals" then
    emergencyCare := "In Accredited Hospitals" &
                     "</br>a. Doctor's Services" &
                     "</br>b. Emergency Room Fees" &
                     "</br>c. Medicines used for immediate relief during treatment" &
                     "</br>d. Oxygem, Intravenous fluids and blood products" &
                     "</br>e. Dressings, conventional casts (plaster of Paris) and sutures" &
                     "</br>f. X-Rays, laboratory and diagnostic examinations, and other medical services related to the emergency treatment of the patient" &
                     "</br>g. Room Upgrade in case of room unavailability" 

else
    emergencyCare := {DBField}
```

Comment: you want to get `crystal` ouptput as exactly as the image?

Comment: yeh same as the image 1. is it possible? if not, is there any other way to do this?

Comment: From where are you getting `Subject to MBL` I mean column 2 values?

Answer (score 0):

Follow the below process since data is hardcoded.

```
1. Create 8 detail sections
2. Dont create any formulas just take 16 text fields
3. Insert line at the bottom of every detail section and on line vertically so that it resembles table.
4. Now write you data as per the your requirement in every text field and preview the report.
```

Let me know if this doesn't work

Edit: if data is from database:

Take 16 formula and write 16 conditions there like first formula:

```
     `if {DBField} = "In Accredited Hospitals" then
        emergencyCare := "In Accredited Hospitals"` 
 if {DBField} = "In Accredited Hospitals" then
        emergencyCare := "a. Doctor's Services"...
```

like that extend to all